# get list of lists from dict of lists by grouping elements at same index in every key-value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary, grouping

I have a dictionary

```
  a = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
```

Now, I wish to convert it into a list of lists such that

```
  [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

i.e. the 1st element of every key-value pair grouped together, every 2nd element grouped together & likewise. Also, number of keys isn't restricted to 2 & can be 'n'

Comment: Have you done any tries on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine with the results being tuples rather than lists an easy way is:

```
list(zip(*a.values()))
```

else sprinkling in some list comprehension can cast to the correct type:

```
[list(value_pair) for value_pair in zip(*a.values())]
```